# How to check SEM assumptions?

Tags: assumptions, structural-equation-modeling, normality-assumption, lavaan

This question is related to SEMs that include latent variables e those that not include in lavaan package.

SEM assumes normality/multivariate normality, but it is being very difficult to found a way to check this in the whole model residuals like we do in regressions.

normality should be checked in each model within SEM? For example:

```
SEMmodel<- ' y1~ x1+x2+x3
             y2~x2+x4'


m1=lm(y1~ x1+x2+x3)
shapiro.test(resid(m1))

m2=lm(y2~x2+x4)
shapiro.test(resid(m2))
```

Instead of shapiro wilk test, how to obtain SEM's residuals histograms and residuals vs fitted? For SEM it is not straight forward as it is for regressions

How to proceed when we add a latent variable? MVN package is appropriate?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, I'd advise against using a test for normality. I'd rather use diagnostics like qq-plots or plot the residuals against the fitted values.

Comment: I prefer this approach too, but I also dont know how to do this is SEMs

Comment: Residuals don't exist in SEMs with latent variables, because there is not a single solution - we know only about the relationships between the latents, we don't know everyone's score on every latent.

Comment: Hi, is it about normality/multivariate normality (MVN) for the residuals or for the items? A very comprehensive and good package to check MVN is the [MVN Package](http://cran.uni-muenster.de/web/packages/MVN/vignettes/MVN.pdf). It outputs several diagnostics (histogram with density dist, q-q-plots) as well as descriptives and implements multiple tests for  univariate normality / multivariate normality